# How to call a Server Side Function in a javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function

I have a button which will execute this when clicked:

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                    "myScript", "AnotherFunction();", true);
}
```

I also have another server side function which is this:

```
public void Delete()
{
  //Delete Code
}
```

After clicking the button, it will now go to this `javascript` function:

Now what i want to do is, call the `Delete()` function on the SERVER side .Here is my javascript function what i have tried so far

```
function (isConfirm) 
{
   if (isConfirm)
   {
       //CALL DELETE FUNCTION HERE Delete();
       swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
   }
   else
   {
       swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
   }
 });
```

How can i call that server side function? Any idea?

Comment: Call it via AJAX, or put it in a web service (or both).

Comment: Use ajax that is the better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in 2 ways. Ajax/Web Service or triggering button click in JS. Most simplest is to trigger button click. Use following code.

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none;"/>
```

c#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Delete();
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('Button1').click();

// jquery
$("#Button1").click();
```

But if you do not want to postback your page then use Ajax.
In Ajax simple, you need to add a webpage say data.aspx, in backend class of data.aspx you to will add following c#

Ajax. C#

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static int DoSomething(int Id)
 {
       return 1;
 }
```

And now you can call this from JS:

```
$.ajax({
            url: APP_PAGE_RELATIVE_PATH + "Data.aspx/DoSomething",
            data: "{'Id':5}",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                // Do Something

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //DebugAlert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a ScriptManager to the page and enable PageMethods;

and code in:

In ASPX:

```xml
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

In Javascript:

```
<script>
     PageMethods.Delete();        
</script>
```

In ASPX.cs:

```cs
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void Delete()
{
     //Delete Code
}
```